# Deploying firebase cloud functions in github actions with firebase-tools not working, but also no error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, firebase-tools

I am trying to run a github actions workflow on each push to the main branch. The workflow is supposed to deploy firebase cloud functions (in the /functions dir).

The whole workflow gets triggered by the push correctly and runs without errors, but the functions do not get deployed.

deploy-cloud-functions-merge.yml

```
name: Deploy Cloud Functions
on:
 workflow_dispatch:
 push:
   branches:
     - main
   paths:
     - 'functions/**'
jobs:
 build_and_deploy:
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
     - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
       with:
         node-version: 16.x
     - name: Build Cloud Functions
       run: cd functions && npm ci
     - name: Create SA key
       run: echo '${{ secrets.CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}' > $HOME/gcloud.json
     - name: Deploy Cloud Functions
       run: export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/gcloud.json && cd functions && npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --project default --json && npx firebase-tools --version
```

The output in github actions from the Deploy Cloud Functions step:

```
Run export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/gcloud.json && cd functions && npx firebase-tools deploy --only functions --project default --json && npx firebase-tools --version
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: firebase-tools@11.23.0
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)

> lint
> eslint

11.23.0
```

So after the predeploy script (lint + eslint), there is no output, but also no error.

When I run `firebase deploy --only functions --project default` on the same project locally, this is what the output looks like:

```
=== Deploying to '[projectname]'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /home/stanley/[projectname]/functions (82.34 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getFileParts(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getCustomMeta(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getCSVParts(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getTemplates(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function getCSVLink(europe-west1)...
✔  functions[getCustomMeta(europe-west1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[getTemplates(europe-west1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[getCSVParts(europe-west1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[getCSVLink(europe-west1)] Successful update operation.
✔  functions[getFileParts(europe-west1)] Successful update operation.
Function URL [functionurl]
Function URL [functionurl]
Function URL [functionurl]
Function URL [functionurl]
Function URL [functionurl]
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: [console-link]
```

I am using `--project default`, to fix a previous error:

```
***
  "status": "error",
  "error": "No project active, but project aliases are available.\n\nRun \u001b[1mfirebase use <alias>\u001b[22m with one of these options:\n\n  default ([projectname])\n  staging ([projectname])"
***
```

this is what my `.firebaserc` looks like:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "[projectname]",
    "staging": "[projectname]"
  },
  "targets": {
    "[projectname]": {
      "hosting": {
        "[projectname]": [
          "[otherprojectname]"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "etags": {}
}
```

I am basically out of solutions and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77337408/1759443

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my comment in [Unable to deploy firebase functions with Github actions, it doesn't recognize a firebase project using Google service account for authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484619/unable-to-deploy-firebase-functions-with-github-actions-it-doesnt-recognize-a).

Do not use firebase use project default (which is the alias). Use the project id instead and consider to write that configuration in a different step like I've mentioned in the other thread.

I hope this works for you too.